# Which application should i define at my eclipse product configuration to treat my application as an Eclipse standard workbench

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, workbench

I have 4 plugins which i 'd like to be installed by default at a new product configuration.I do not want to provide an update mechanism through a feature for my clients.The plugins are parts of a GMF editor.The final plugin which holds the diagram editor code has been created not as an RCP app but as plugin code ,which has been tested succefully.

My desire is to make a new Eclipse product and put these plugins as dependencies

So i made a new empty plugin,i defined a new product configuration file with all the plugins and their dependencies defined at the product configuration file and then at my new plugin.xml file i created a new extention of the org.eclipse.core.runtime.product extention point with the name value and application name defined.I have also validated my plug-ins dependencies and cliked the "Add Required Plug-ins"

I undestand that the product should be associated with an application.In my case the application for my product i would like to be a new eclipse workbench as the one that i have installed and is running.So i defined as application the org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench but when i am trying to lauch my new product i am getting an error:
`Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" not in the registry`.
How could i define the standard eclipse workbench for my product which is not an rcp app?Is this the right one?Whatever application i am choosing i am getting the same error.
I think that there must be a default way to define your wrapper application as an eclipse standard environment.
Is it?Or i have to write a new IApplication by my own?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include your Eclipse plug-ins as part of a standard Eclipse configuration, you perform the following steps.

- Unzip a fresh version of Eclipse to your hard drive.
- Add your plug-ins to the fresh Eclipse
- Zip the fresh Eclipse, and distribute.

Comment: And what if i want to take advantage of splash icons ,launching and branching capabilities of the eclipse product framework?

Comment: For a splash image, you have to write an Eclipse RCP that includes your plug-ins.  I'm not sure what you mean by launching and branching in this context.

Comment: Ok,this is a solution but i think the goal of the "product" configuration files is to organize your eclipse-like products in a more structured and precise way.And i think that there is a standard application from the eclipse's bundles that should be accosiated with your product if it is not an RCP where you define your own application

Comment: I'm confused by your last comment.  Either you have an Eclipse plug-in, which extends the functionality of the Eclipse IDE, or you have a product, which is what Eclipse RCP was designed to help you make.  If you're creating your own application, you can use Eclipse RCP.